# How long is AppleCare+ "Paid in Full" for a 16" MacBook Pro in November 2021

Tags: applecare

I'm about to buy AppleCare+. Apple lists 2 options

1. Annual ($149 per year)
2. Paid in Full ($399)

[image]

---

[image]

I can't find anywhere where it list how long "Paid in Full" coverage lasts. It's not under "learn more.

- It's not here: https://www.apple.com/support/products/mac/
- It's not here: https://www.apple.com/legal/sales-support/applecare/applecareplus/1021/111221_applecareplusmacus.pdf (arrived at from here: https://www.apple.com/legal/sales-support/applecare/applecareplus/us/mac/)

That last one says at most

> For Fixed-Term Plans, your Plan Term is fixed as set forth on your Plan Confirmation.

I went through the purchase process, adding credit card, etc, and even up to the last confirmation page I was never told what I was purchasing (what the plan term is)

What is the plan term for the "Paid in Full" option? It certainly can't just be 2 incidents indefinitely. I doubt I could get support in 2050 for this 2021 Mac.

Answer (score 5):

I contacted Apple Support. The first support agent on chat told me

> Ok. Apple Care+ extends your coverage to 2 years from your AppleCare+ purchase date and adds up to two incidents of accidental damage protection every 12 months. However it will not cover the theft or lost product.

> You can also check that in the below link.

> https://www.apple.com/support/products/mac/

When I pointed out nothing on that page said 2 years and that that would make the "Paid in Full" option more expensive than the annual option the service representative transferred me to a different division in charge of AppleCare+

The first person on the AppleCare+ line just read the Terms of Service linked above. When I pointed out what they just read to me didn't list a time they escalated to an "Expert"

The "Expert" claimed it was 3 years of coverage and that I'd be able to renew annually after. When I asked where was this written they spent ~10 minutes looking and then escalated to another expert.

That expert verified that it is listed no where online making it impossible to compare plans. They claimed "Paid in Full" coverage is 3 years.

So, after 45 minutes of my time, that means effectively you save $48 for paying up front ($399 vs $447)

Comment: I suspect there is some variation by country.  The AU page https://www.apple.com/au/legal/statutory-warranty/au/ clearly says 3 years for any Mac (purchased in AU).

Comment: Or take the bet that any repairs within the three years (outside of statutory warranty) are going to be less than $400.